# BeautifulSoup only identifies 5 out of 25 entries

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to collect data (model, kilometer, price) about used cars on a retail site that displays 25 entries per page. It works fine for the first 5 entries but then it stops and doesn't collect the data from the remaining 20 entries. The tags for all 25 entries are identical, so I don't understand why it stops after 5. Thanks for your help!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


counter=0
    

page = requests.get('https://www.willhaben.at/iad/gebrauchtwagen/auto/ford-gebrauchtwagen/mustang')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for Inhalt_1 in soup.find_all('div', class_='Box-wfmb7k-0 hkyQgZ'):
    print(Inhalt_1.h3.text)
print()
for Inhalt_2 in soup.find_all('span', class_='Text-sc-10o2fdq-0 fiVXiu'):
    print(Inhalt_2.text)
print()    
for Inhalt_3 in soup.find_all('div', class_='Text-sc-10o2fdq-0 fTyYiu'):
    if (counter+1)%2==0:
        print(Inhalt_3.span.text, 'km')
    counter +=1
```

Output:

```
Ford Mustang Cabrio 2,3 Turbo Ecoboost 317 Ps Autom Leder Klima
Ford Mustang V6
Ford Mustang 5,0 Ti-VCT V8 GT
Ford Mustang Shelby GT500
Ford Mustang Ford Mustang Mach I Coupe

€ 32.900
€ 16.500
€ 32.500
€ 79.800
€ 49.500

77.900 km
113.000 km
111.000 km
21.879 km
100.000 km
```

Comment: I assume the website only loads 5 elements at first and populates them as use scrolls towards bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Bijay Regmi for the hint. In fact the website only loads the upper part unless one scrolls down. To do this automatically, one could use e.g. selenium webdriver to scroll down the whole webpage (if you jump immediatly to the bottom of the site, the intermediate part will not load). Here is the solution.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time


counter=0
Y=1080
    

page= "https://www.willhaben.at/iad/gebrauchtwagen/auto/ford-gebrauchtwagen/mustang"
PATH = "/Applications/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    
driver.get(page)

for i in range(5):      
    scroller1=i*Y
    scroller2=(i+1)*Y
    Order="window.scrollTo("+str(scroller1)+", "+str(scroller2)+")"
    driver.execute_script(Order) 
    time.sleep(0.2)
        
pageSource = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource, 'lxml')
```

The outcome corretly shows all 25 entries!

Answer (score 0):

Use a mobile phone user agent for your request it would work

```
page=requests.get('https://www.willhaben.at/iad/gebrauchtwagen/auto/ford-gebrauchtwagen/mustang' , headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B137 Safari/601.1'} )
```

Also try by setting the stream attributes to true and use this code

```
for line in r.iter_lines():

    if line:
        print(json.loads(line))
```